# Ionic2 tabs/app,ts passing value

Tags: firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I need to pass value from tabs.ts to each page of tabs. So I have something like this:

```
constructor(public navParams: NavParams) { 
...// config 

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // If there's a user take him to the home page.
    this.user = [];
    this.user.push(user);
    this.rootPage = HomePage;


  } else {
    // If there's no user logged in send him to the LoginPage
    this.rootPage = LoginPage;
  }
});
}

this.tab1Root = HomePage;
this.tab4Root = ProfilePage;
```

How to pass value (user) to each page of tabs? I tried with few combinations of this code but doesnt work (getting some erros - e.g If I put this.tab1Root... to onAuthStateChanged method, then it gives me: "Maximum call stack size exceeded"). Here are docs: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/tabs/Tab/ - I understand 90% of this but still dont know how I should pass this value...

My second question - is there any better way to take current user and pass him as value to each page? Will be better if I use provider or something?

Third question: it is good to have this code in tabs.ts than in app.ts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [rootParams] attribute in ion-tab

```
<ion-tab ... [rootParams]="user"></ion-tab>
```

In tab file:

```
constructor(navParams: NavParams) {
    console.log("Passed params", navParams.data.user);
}
```

Second way is using events: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Events/
It allows you to share data between any of your pages.

Provider is a good option.

3. It depends. Better way is to make an authorization once - using provider inside app.ts - when app starts.